# OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion Server apache MultiViews trouble

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, mac-osx-server

I have a trouble with server I cannot disable MultiViews correctly.
on /Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/sites/0000_any_80_wthr.proj.conf
I see config for my host

```
<VirtualHost wthr.proj:80>
ServerName wthr.proj
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
DocumentRoot "/Users/i/Sites/wthr.proj"
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php /wiki/ default.html
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_log combinedvhost
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_log

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    SSLEngine Off
    SSLCipherSuite "ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM"
    SSLProtocol -ALL +SSLv3 +TLSv1
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLProxyProtocol -ALL +SSLv3 +TLSv1
</IfModule>

<Directory "/Users/i/Sites/wthr.proj">
    Options All -Indexes -ExecCGI -Includes +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    <IfModule mod_dav.c>
        DAV Off
    </IfModule>
    <IfDefine !WEBSERVICE_ON>
        Deny from all
        ErrorDocument 403 /customerror/websitesoff403.html
    </IfDefine>
</Directory>
```

Like this my problem is MultiViews. My cms uses mod_rewrite for example paths /translate /search is not folders. This URI requests processes index.php file all requests processing do index.php file. And cms have for example modules with some name search.inc.php, translate.inc.php.

And when I type in browser /translate I get 404 error. 
See log:

```
[Wed Dec 05 13:41:04 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /Users/i/Sites/wthr.proj/translate (None could be negotiated).
[Wed Dec 05 13:41:05 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /Users/i/Sites/wthr.proj/translate (None could be negotiated).
[Wed Dec 05 13:41:15 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /Users/i/Sites/wthr.proj/translate (None could be negotiated).
[Wed Dec 05 13:42:55 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /Users/i/Sites/wthr.proj/translate (None could be negotiated).
[Wed Dec 05 13:42:56 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /Users/i/Sites/wthr.proj/translate (None could be negotiated).
```

When I delete translate.inc.php(is part of cms)-All ok I cache URI in my index.php.
When I setup -MultiViews OR delete MultiViews word from Options string in 0000_any_80_wthr.proj.conf.

All ok. BUT see log.

```
    in /Users/i/Sites/wthr.proj/translate.inc.php on line 19
[Wed Dec 05 13:45:01 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Parse error:  parse error in /Users/i/Sites/wthr.proj/translate.inc.php on line 19
[Wed Dec 05 13:45:02 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Parse error:  parse error in /Users/i/Sites/wthr.proj/translate.inc.php on line 19
[Wed Dec 05 13:45:12 2012] [notice] child pid 11462 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Wed Dec 05 13:45:13 2012] [notice] child pid 11466 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Wed Dec 05 13:45:14 2012] [notice] child pid 11468 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Wed Dec 05 13:45:14 2012] [notice] child pid 11467 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Wed Dec 05 13:45:15 2012] [notice] child pid 11471 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Wed Dec 05 13:45:15 2012] [notice] child pid 11469 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

Around 50% requests failed (child pid 11468 exit signal Segmentation fault).

How i can disable MultiViews correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You have in your `Options`:

```
+MultiViews
```

To disable it, you need to change it to:

```
-MultiViews
```

Comment: It's partly helpful but Apache goes crazy - "exit signal Segmentation fault (11)" on around 50% requests.

Answer (score 0):

No, dear Michael it's not helpful, because i tried setup -MultiViews too.
With result

```
[Wed Dec 05 13:45:12 2012] [notice] child pid 11462 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Wed Dec 05 13:45:13 2012] [notice] child pid 11466 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Wed Dec 05 13:45:14 2012] [notice] child pid 11468 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Wed Dec 05 13:45:14 2012] [notice] child pid 11467 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Wed Dec 05 13:45:15 2012] [notice] child pid 11471 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Wed Dec 05 13:45:15 2012] [notice] child pid 11469 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```